# java-8 Predicated with parameter

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

For java8 in action example :: https://github.com/java8/Java8InAction/blob/master/src/main/java/lambdasinaction/chap1/FilteringApples.java

```
 public static boolean isGreenApple(Apple apple), 
 public static boolean isHeavyApple(Apple apple) {
```

I want to add a similar method e.g

```
public static boolean isAppleOfColor(Apple apple, String color)
```

And i want to access it using same pattern ::

```
 List<Apple> colorApples = filterApples(inventory, FilteringApples::isAppleOfColor("red"));
```

But I can't pass arguments in FilteringApples::isAppleOfColor("red").

So far I have achieved this using following :

```
public static Predicate<Apple> colourMatches( String color) {
    return p->color.equals(p.getColor());
}
```

and then calling

```
  List<Apple> colorApples = filterApples(inventory, (Apple a)->a.colourMatchesOnApple("red"));
    System.out.println(colorApples);
```

This works. But is there a way I can use the "referred" parameterized methods like `FilteringApples::isAppleOfColor("red").`

thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks All, I just realized in JLS 15.13 : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13 as following text:

> It is not possible to specify a particular signature to be matched,
>   for example, Arrays::sort(int[]). Instead, the functional interface
>   provides argument types that are used as input to the overload
>   resolution algorithm (§15.12.2). This should satisfy the vast majority
>   of use cases; when the rare need arises for more precise control, a
>   lambda expression can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method reference cannot capture additional variables.

What you can do is

```
List<Apple> colorApples = filterApples(inventory, a -> isAppleOfColor(a, "red"));
```

which you will note is shorter.

Note: I would avoid using a `static` method esp when the first argument is a type you are writing. Much better to add

```
// added to Apple
public boolean isColor(String color)
```

and you can call

```
List<Apple> colorApples = filterApples(inventory, a -> a.isColor("red"));
```

which is likely to be the same as

```
List<Apple> colorApples = inventory.stream()
                                   .filter(a -> a.isColor("red"))
                                   .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Yes thanks, adding it to apple, also works and in that case we even don't need method to be static.

I was wondering on Method reference, which you have clarified that it can not capture additional variables. 

I tried checking JLS and somehow missed it. It will be great if you have JLS section handy for my understanding.

Comment: @Optional note: method references can capture a value left of `::` only. e.g. `Consumer<String> out = System.out::println;` captures `System.out`

Comment: Note that in this specific example, only a constant value is supplied as method argument, but no variable captured. That’s still something not supported by method references, so a lambda expression is required, but the lambda expression is *non-capturing*, which can have a performance benefit over capturing lambdas.

Comment: Thanks All, I just realized in JLS 15.13 : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13 as following text:

It is not possible to specify a particular signature to be matched, for example, Arrays::sort(int[]). Instead, the functional interface provides argument types that are used as input to the overload resolution algorithm (§15.12.2). This should satisfy the vast majority of use cases; when the rare need arises for more precise control, a lambda expression can be used.

I will update this to my question